# Not able to configure uwgi via supervisor " uwsgi:uwsgi_00: ERROR (spawn error) "

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

i've django application running with uwsgi and nginx. I was using uwsgi python package to configure uwsgi manually. Now i need to switch to supervisor to run the uwsgi process. I create the supervisor config and started the uwsgi processes and the site is working but i'm getting the following error when i start the uwsgi process using supervisorctl command

> uwsgi:uwsgi_00: ERROR (spawn error)

But there are 8 processes created in the server. I'm not sure why i'm getting this error then.

I'm attaching my supervisor config and uwsgi.ini file

```
[program:uwsgi]
command=/var/www/django/virtual/bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/django/uwsgi.ini 
user=root
process_name = %(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/django/super.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/django/super.log
```

Uwsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
 master          = true 
 socket          = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
 chmod-socket    = 666
 chdir           = /var/www/django/webserver_test
 wsgi-file       = /var/www/django/webserver_test/Django_app/wsgi.py
 virtualenv      = /var/www/django/virtual
 pythonpath      = /var/www/django/virtual/bin/python
 vacuum          = true
 enable-threads  = true
 daemonize= /var/www/django/uwsgi.log
```

Supervisor error log:

> 2017-05-29 09:49:50,953 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi_00' with pid 20819
>   2017-05-29 09:49:50,978 INFO exited: uwsgi_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
>   2017-05-29 09:49:51,979 INFO gave up: uwsgi_00 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
>   2017-05-29 10:01:52,874 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi_00' with pid 20993
>   2017-05-29 10:01:52,906 INFO exited: uwsgi_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
>   2017-05-29 10:01:53,914 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi_00' with pid 20998
>   2017-05-29 10:01:53,932 INFO exited: uwsgi_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
>   2017-05-29 10:01:55,941 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi_00' with pid 21005
>   2017-05-29 10:01:55,966 INFO exited: uwsgi_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
>   2017-05-29 10:01:58,976 INFO spawned: 'uwsgi_00' with pid 21013
>   2017-05-29 10:01:58,994 INFO exited: uwsgi_00 (exit status 0; not expected)
>   2017-05-29 10:01:59,995 INFO gave up: uwsgi_00 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

And the server configuration is 1 core, 2GB RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I have given daemonize in uwsgi configuration. Supervisor daemonize itself. So there was a conflict between uwsgi and supervisor. I remove "daemonize= /var/www/django/uwsgi.log" for uwsgi config and this fixed the issue.